# Animated text on the ring from LOTR

Tags: animation

Can anyone point me in the right direction on making animated text appear like the inscription on the ring, from Lord of the Rings? You know the part where Gandalf pulls the ring out of the fire at Frodo's house and the inscription has this "burn in effect as it appears?

Many thanks

Comment: There are [plenty of tutorials around for the ring](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+one+ring&tbm=vid) its just a matter of simply adding an animated mask over the textures for the effect to appear gradually

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yes good idea. I ended up spending a little more time learning from a couple of tutorials and it has done me good :-) Now I can acheive the effect I was after. Thanks for replying!